# Have a question about training routine

Tags: training

I am 17 years old 180cm and i weight 70kg and I train 6 days a week, around 1 hour per day and my routine is pretty much like this monday-legs abs and biceps, tuesday -chest, tricep and bicep, wednesday- shoulders, Jack and bíceps, i then just repeat that plano the resto of the week AM i doin it right?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about your routine ? Meaning reps, sets etc... Depending on how much and what exercises you do the answer will vary. Also what are your goals ? For how long have you been training ? Are you satisfied with the results ?

Comment: Hey, for every exercise i do 3 sets of 15 reps, everyday for bíceps i train with dumbells with 10kg on each si de and do around 9-12 sets of 3-4 different exercises but Mainly bicep curls and hammer curls, for chest i use the PEC deck machine with around 42 kg and Raising it after every rep , il use cable fly aswell and then dumbells in the press bench, for back i also use the pec deck machine , Bent o ver barbel deadlift and wide gripe pulo ups and for shoulders i do los pulley raise, alternate front raise and barbell front raise all of that with the weight i can handle for the 15 reps

Comment: Aldo i have been takin milk protein shake  after every workout, i would love to know if im taking it right and some people told me that i shouldnt train everyday the same muscle (bicep). And to answer if im seeing any results, i havê gained 5 kg in 3 months but i just started this routine 2 weeks ago, after that i would just go everyday and just do what i felt Luke training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for adding more info in the comments.

I wouldn't say your routine is bad, but here are a few things to remember when designing a workout routine:

**I Progressive overload**

As a beginner, you need very little stimulus to progress. You can do 2 sets of 12 reps 3 times a week and see massive results.
The volume (weight * sets * reps) that you do for each body part seems very high for a beginner.

The problem is this: There is a point where your body gets used to the training stimulus and will need more to progress.

Let's say you start by doing 2 sets of 12 reps 3 times a week. After a few weeks/months, you won't see as much results. To trigger more reaction, all you need to do is start doing 3 or 4 sets of 12 reps 3 times a week. It is still reasonable. Then after a few weeks add a seconds exercise for example. Then more reps/weight/sets. Build up the volume over the years to keep progressing and counter the ability of your body to adapt.

However if you start straight away like you did by doing quite a lot of volume, you won't have much room left for increased stimulus. Doing 9-12 sets total for each body part is a lot. When you hit a plateau, you'll have to go up to 15 or even 20 sets. Maybe play on frequency too.

[Here is an interesting study on progressive overload](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25559905)

**II Muscle protein synthesis**

Training your biceps every day is not an issue itself. Biceps are fairly small muscles and recover fast. However you don't get the full benefit of muscle protein synthesis response after a workout. It lasts for 48 hours.

You could try training them every other day instead and let them fully rest before hitting them again. See if it works for you.

[You can read about it here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11255140)

**III What I would do**

Just to add up on this and be more precise. Here is what I would do, assuming that your goal is aesthetics:

Train 3 times a week. Full-body routine. Starting with the main lifts (Squat, bench, deadlift) for 3 sets of 5-8. Adding 2.5/5 pounds every time or change for a variation of the main lift.
Then move on to accessory movements. One for each body part. 3 sets of 8-12. Add weight if possible every time/change the exercise.

*Full example*

- Back Squat: 3 sets of 5
- Bench Press: 3 sets of 5
- Deadlift: 2 sets of 5
- OHP: 3 sets of 8
- Bent-over Rows: 3 sets of 8
- Triceps extensions: 2 sets of 12
- Bicep curl: 3 sets of 12
- Upright Rows: 2 sets of 12
- Leg Raises: 2 sets of 12
- Calves Raises: 2 sets of 20

Then go home, eat well, sleep well, avoid stress, drugs. Repeat.
This is just an example, feel free to add/change to whatever you like the best.

I hope this helps !

**EDIT**

Just to clarify about your routine. I think it is good, but a bit too advanced for someone who can still gain 5 kg in 3 months. Start with less, build over time and it will pay off more in the long run.